# Code sign Error on xcode 4.3.2 and ios 5.1

Tags: iphone, ios5

I create a demo application on my mac pc with the xcode 5.1.When i try to create a release build i am getting this error

```
 codeSign error :code signing required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'IOS 5.1'.
```

I already create the required certificates for the system.

Please help me out.

Comment: where did you get xcode 5.1, I want too.

Comment: You probably mean the 5.1 SDK as most recent version of Xcode to date is 4.4. Speaking of which indicating the (correct) version of Xcode might help a bit. Last, are you sure you are a registered iOS developer (short: did you pay $99 ?) (there is no easy way to test on a device without beeing such)

Comment: @tikhop: probably it is [xcode 4 with iOS sdk 5.1](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/index.php).

Comment: Yes, Olotiar it is xcode 4.3.2 and ios 5.1 Sorry i am bit of confused between the versions.

Answer (score 0):

try this: Select right code sign that match your bundle id.

[image]

Comment: @Anshul, already installed provisioning profile(with same bundle id) and developer certificate in your system?